# Automate building and installing of multiple targets in xcode project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6

1. I have made an app, which has multiple number of targets (around 10 targets). Now, when I have to make a build and run it on device, it takes a lot of time and energy to run all the targets one by one. Is there any tool/way through which I can automate the building and installing of apps to the device?
2. Similarly, I would also like to know if we can automate the "archive" and "submit to appstore" process too? Like, I run a command and all targets archive and get submitted to appstore themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a script which runs `xcodebuild` with different arguments for each of the different targets.

There is also Application Loader’s command-line tool, which will allow you to extend this script to automatically upload the binaries to the app store.

Comment: Yes, what exactly to use.. if I use xcodebuild install, it says "** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **", but it does not show it on the device. Any idea how to install it on device through command line? only then can I write script

Comment: I think you need 3rd party support to access that, like https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap or something more up to date

Comment: I did research before posting the question here, but couldn't find anything other than fruitstrap. Problem is, fruitstrap is not being maintained now, so it might break in some time.